# PHP time ago(returns wrong time)

Tags: php, mysql, time

For a long time I have been struggling with `time ago` function. Basically I store posts/comments in mysql database with date `timestamp`. Later, I want to display added time ago, for example `53 minutes ago`.

I store user timezone into mysql db, and I want to display this `time ago` function using the user's timezone.

But, my function returns wrong value, for example - I live in UTC + 2 and time in my country is 11:54. If I add new post, and check db, post added time is 11:54, but when I want to display time ago (It need to be 10 seconds ago), it shows added `1 hour, 59 minutes, 50 seconds ago` and goes down like `1 hour, 56 minutes, 26 seconds ago`.

[image: Car paradise screenshot - red box]

---

Get Timezone function

```
if(isset($userRow['timezone'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set($userRow['timezone']);
}elseif(isset($_COOKIE['timeZone'])) {
    date_default_timezone_set($_COOKIE['timeZone']);
}
```

Call time_elapsed function

```
<?php echo $user->time_elapsed($datevariable); ?>
```

time_elapsed function

```
function time_elapsed($datetime, $full = 7) {
    $now = new DateTime;
    $ago = new DateTime($datetime);
    $diff = $now->diff($ago);

    echo "</br>";
    echo "echo db timestamp for test: ";
    echo $datetime;
    echo "</br>";

    $diff->w = floor($diff->d / 7);
    $diff->d -= $diff->w * 7;

    $string = array(
            'y' => 'year',
            'm' => 'month',
            'w' => 'week',
            'd' => 'day',
            'h' => 'hour',
            'i' => 'minute',
            's' => 'second',
    );
    foreach ($string as $k => &$v) {
            if ($diff->$k) {
                    $v = $diff->$k . ' ' . $v . ($diff->$k > 1 ? 's' : '');
            } else {
                    unset($string[$k]);
            }
    }

    if (!$full) $string = array_slice($string, 0, 1);
    return $string ? implode(', ', $string) . ' ago' : 'just now';
}
```

Comment: You'll always be safer converting everything to UTC and then doing time math based on the common time zone.  Definitely store everything at UTC. That avoids all kinds of problems with server and user timezones. Treat it as separating data from display.

Comment: @GianfrancescoAurecchia maybe the italian "fuso orario" can be "timezone" in english. Also: OP is asking for a fix on a PHP code. The fix shouldn't be to use a JS one. Do you agree?

Comment: yes, you're right, thanks, I removed my post

Answer (score 1):

what it could be happening is that PHP is using a default timezone, is saved on your `php.ini` file `date.timezone`. You can see it using `phpinfo();` and looking for date.timezone. You may need to change it there.

Available timezones in case you need them: [PHP timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

Comment: Default timezone in php.ini is blank.